# Remove dev/loop

Tags: 20.04

```
┌─╼ [~]
└╼ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  453G  177G  253G  42% /
tmpfs                        7.6G  139M  7.4G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                    56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop3                   163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop4                    65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/nvme0n1p1               704M  302M  351M  47% /boot
tmpfs                        1.6G   76K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0                    33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop6                    56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop5                   139M  139M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1536
/dev/loop1                    33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/home/infinity/.Private      453G  177G  253G  42% /home/infinity
/dev/loop7                   139M  139M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1557
```

I have a lot of `dev/loop*` and other useless things here. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 3):

The /dev/loop devices are mounted by snaps - applications.  In your case just the base packages, and chromium.

Ubuntu can run without snaps, but it is becoming more difficult.

Comment: So you suggest I don't delete them?

Comment: I used to remove the snaps from my system, but have found that with the current versions of Ubuntu some functionality is lost when I do that.  So do save them.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 here without ANY snap and working flawlessly ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind  It works great, unless you want to use the software store!  My concern (mine alone) is that Ubuntu will become reliant upon snaps to the point that the system is no longer usable without them.

Comment: Example: The CUPS printing stack Snap is currently in testing (try it!). Eventually the developers hope to drop the deb-based stack.

Comment: Please don't do that to cups until after 22.04 so I can at least use that for its lifetime :(

Comment: Unfortunately, two of the apps I used all the time are only snaps now.  Live Patch and Bitwarden.  I do often wonder about space usage as snaps are self contained with all dependencies included in them, so really don't they actually use more space?

Comment: @Terrance I have no hard numbers to go on, but I live at the bottom of a 10 Mbps DSL line, and snaps take forever to download.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I'm on a bonded 40Mbps DSL, and they take a while for me too, so I feel your pain.  :)

Comment: @Terrance Every day I chant "starlink, starlink, starlink".  Then I spin around and toss a pinch of salt over my shoulder.  It hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs
```

The `-x` (e**X**clude) option is used to ignore filesystems that you don't care to know about.

You can also create an alias for `df` using one of the following `echo` commands below. The first one will append your aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` (Ubuntu's default `~/.bashrc` sources this file) or — if you are using another distro, e.g. Fedora — you can just add the alias to the end of your Home's `.bashrc`

For Ubuntu users:

```
echo "alias df='df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

For other *nix users:

```
echo "alias df='df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Don't forget to source it:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

Enjoy :-)